# How to handle issues with Connections cannot be made(either DB or external systems) when multiple connections are available

Tags: c#, error-handling, connection, integration-testing, ems

I have question regarding handling the multiple connections. These connections can be either DB connection, SOA connection, EMS connection etc.....

Lets say I have 1 database connection where I pull data and I have 2 EMS connections both having different data and independent. The data is sent to EMS and update the status whether the data is successfully sent or not.

1) If the database connection is down or any other issues when we cannot access database
2) Any 1 EMS connection is down, the application should continue processing the other EMS connection.
3) What happens if we are able to send data to EMS, but cannot update the DB status bcos of database issues, what are we suppose to do with all the messages that are in memory and we need to send to EMS.
4) Cannot establish connection to 1 EMS, but the other were are able to establish and therefore the application should process that EMS messages.

These are some of the -ve test cases which I have to handle. Please feel free to let me know if any other issues I have to tackle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple connections to different sources, sounds like a good solution for System.Transactions (if EMS supports this).

Try something like this, this way all 3 operation eithr succeed or fail as a unit of work.

```
        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope())
            {
                Method1Save(); //DB
                Method2Save(); //EMS1
                Method3Save(); //EMS2
                tran.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Problem " + ex.ToString());
        }
```

If EMS does't support a TransactionScope, then you will have to handle it manaully, probably by putting the transaction on the connection itself and then committing all the transactions once the operations succeed, which means keeping the connections open longer for each data source.

Comment: I am already using TransactionScope. Let me give u an example. We read data from DB. Lets say we have 500 records, we run 5 threads to process the data and send to EMS. What should we do if EMS failed to accept message, either queue is full or some connection issues, do we have restart the application or wait or some time and try again. If try again how many times and also what about the other threads, if we already know its failing, do we let the other threads try send the message or let all the threads wait for some time and try again.

Comment: another case. If we want to update the status to DB that message is sent successfully or failed. What happens if we sent the message to EMS, but cannot update the DB bcos of issue. Do we let the other messages to be sent to EMS or wait until the DB connection is resolved, bcos if the status is not updated, then it will try to send the same message again which we already sent it.

Comment: @Bunny - For a thread fail, maybe set a threshold on the number of thread fails before cancelling all of the other threads.  You don't want to stop if there is a slight blip (can just re-queue the failure), but if the database is down, no need pestering it.  Also, you might look at th database error more closely and see if segregate connection errors versus non-connection errors.

Comment: @Bunny - If you sent the message to BMS and the DB is down, then you need to store the message in a temporary store until the DB is back up. Maybe this is in memory or persisted to the file system as XML or other format. Then once the database is back up, you would process the sent messages in the temp store first before processing any new messages.  Basically you would need a secondary storage system to handle this case to temporary hold the message until it could be saved to the DB.

Comment: I have to send messages to 2 EMS Queue. Lets say if the first queue is down and 2nd queue is working. If the thread count is 3. All the 3 threads send message to first queue which is down. I am using a secondary storage but thats for only the failed messages and the failed messages are retried on a different thread which is single threaded to maintain the order. So everytime any EMS is done, all the other EMS messages are processed. When all the messages are finished, we get fresh messages except the failed messages, bcos it has to process the failed messages first.